# Como encontrar arquivos não utilizados em um projeto?

Tags: linux, arquivo, aplicação-web, projeto-de-software

Temos um projeto web que mudou o layout diversas vezes e muitos arquivos não vão ser mais utilizados. Porém, como há diversos desenvolvedores utilizando arquivos ao mesmo tempo, os arquivos antigos foram mantidos até que toda a alteração fosse finalizada.

Preciso de um comando para Linux em que ele busque os nomes dos arquivos de imagens, css, html e etc de dentro de uma pasta específica e liste todos que não são mais utilizados.

Comment: Complicado isso. Não tem nada dinâmico no projeto? E se houver nomes parciais, como em frameworks onde você configura a extensão em um local? E em frameworks que usam convenções de nomes para encontrar automaticamente arquivos? Este é um tipo de coisa que até dá pra fazer, mas depende muito da tecnologia. O ideal, do meu ponto de vista, seria montar algum documento de rastreabilidade partindo das funcionalidades visíveis do sistema e identificando qual arquivo é usado e aonde. O que sobrar é candidato à exclusão.

Comment: Os arquivos que preciso encontrar são todos estáticos mesmo, porque são basicamente apenas arquivos de alteração visual/layout.

Comment: Não é uma questão adequadamente classificada como **projeto-de-software** (*software design*). Remover esta marca facilitará a localização de questões.

Answer (score 2):

Isso deve listar para você os arquivos não acessados ou modificados nos ultimos 30 dias:

```
ls -l `find * -mtime +30`
```

Você pode alterar o número de dias modificando o "+30" do exemplo para o número de dias desejado.

Talvez encontrar listar os arquivos antigos dessa forma possa te ajudar a filtrar o que deseja.

Comment: O problema neste caso é que para imagens e css isso não funciona, porque eles são apenas utilizados, não alterados.

Comment: Você pode tentar o mesmo comando trocando -mtime por -atime